# MS excel 2010 using average formula with filter data

Tags: excel, average

Say you have a list of numbers
-2.32
6.48
9.71
0.95
16.53
28.21
-11.15
-4.96
-1.57
-12.98
-25.82
2.59
-3.64
-6.79
0.18
-4.84
6.94

How do you efficiently get the average of the numbers between -2 & 0 from this list

Answer (score 4):

You can use `AVERAGEIFS`. Say you have your data in a range `A1:A20`.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(A1:A20,A1:A20,">=-2",A1:A20,"<=0")
```

Answer (score 0):

@James gave a great answer since you mentioned Excel 2010. For compatibility with Excel 2003 and earlier, you can use an array formula:

```
=SUM((A1:A17)*(A1:A17>=-2)*(A1:A17<=0))/SUM((A1:A17>=-2)*(A1:A17<=0))
```

Use Shift-Ctrl-Enter to enter this function.

Comment: For an array formula, average function would be better, I think `=AVERAGE(IF(A1:A17>-2,IF(A1:A17<0,A1:A17)))`